# add item to drop dwon list visible but not avialable for select (only show as Title)

Tags: asp.net

How I can add item to drop down list and make some of them visible but no body can select it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using Java Script on "onchange" event of DDL, You can check text or value of selected option & you can return true of false on the basis of your criteria.